Нет Диспетчера конфигурации SQL Server
Установил SSMS, не могу ни где найти диспетчер конфигурации а без него не работает студия, не могу подключиться. Уже смотрел в system32, в управлении компьютером, в службах, нигде нету.
Если что 11 винда.

Попробуйте по пути открыть "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager16.msc" (версия может быть другой не 16). Кстати какая у вас версия SQL Server?
